# create a new text file in IBM i IFS directory

Tags: ibm-midrange

How do you create a new text file in IBM i (as/400) Integrated File System (IFS) from green screen command line or maybe in ACS or Navigator tools?

I usually just copy an old file, but I realized I don't know create a new file using IBM i command. No F6=Create option in WRKLNK.  Going through on line help was not productive.

```
  CPY OBJ('/home/myFile.txt') TOOBJ('/home/NEWUSER/MyNewFile.txt')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want a text file, you can use `EDTF` to create an empty IFS file and open an editor against it. So:

```
EDTF 'test.txt'
```

will create a file named `test.txt` in the IFS in your home directory which is usually `/home/<user name>`.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to use the `QSH` command and run the `touch` shell command.

```
QSH CMD('touch /path/to/ifs/file.txt')
```

You can add the '-C nnnn' parameter if you want to set the CCSID of the file that is created.